# How to change the hidden input value to default if user hides the field?

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have a number type input field. This input field is initially hidden. If the user clicks on some radio button then this input gets displayed.

This input field has a `min` `max` and `default` value specified. I have two radio buttons. When I click on the custom radio button it displays the input number field and in there the user might give some invalid inputs so that form gets invalid even after user hides this input by clicking on the the radio button.

To solve this issue I want to clear the input number field and set its value to the default which is `1` here if the input field gets hidden?

```
 <form action="">
     <label><input type="radio" value="all" onclick="javascript:chooseTableRows();" name="option" >All</label><br>
     <label><input id="custom" value="custom" type="radio" name="option" onclick="javascript:chooseTableRows();">Custom</label><br>
     <div id="rows" style="display:none;">
     <input type="number" name="rows" min="1" value="1" max="10" required></div>
      <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
   </form>
```

```js
function chooseTableRows() {
    if (document.getElementById('custom').checked) {
        document.getElementById('rows').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('rows').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the else just reset the value to 1 like below.

```
function chooseTableRows() {
    if (document.getElementById('custom').checked) {
        document.getElementById('rows').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('rows').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByName('rows')[0].value = 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) in your `else` condition and set it to `1` if the custom checkbox is not checked.

**Live Demo**

```js
function chooseTableRows() {
  //check box
  var row = document.getElementById('rows')
  //Number input
  var custInput = document.getElementById('number')
  //Check if custom is checked
  if (document.getElementById('custom').checked) {
    row.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    row.style.display = 'none';
    custInput.value = 1; //set value to 1
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label><input type="radio" value="all" onclick="javascript:chooseTableRows();" name="option">All</label><br>
  <label><input id="custom" value="custom" type="radio" name="option" onclick="javascript:chooseTableRows();">Custom</label><br>
  <div id="rows" style="display:none;">
    <input type="number" id="number" name="rows" min="1" value="1" max="10" required></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```